# "Cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d320d.lib'" Error

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get OpenCV to work with visual studio. After following the official OpenCV installation instructions down to the letter, I tried building a sample program. I got the error in the title. The odd part is that the namespace 'cv' works fine - there are no errors for the rest of the code. Here's the sample program I tried to build:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << " Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file
    if (image.empty()) // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    imshow("Display window", image); // Show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

In addition, here's my list of additional dependencies that I put in the project properties:

```
opencv_calib3d320d.lib
opencv_core320d.lib
opencv_features2d320d.lib
opencv_flann320d.lib
opencv_highgui320d.lib
opencv_imgcodecs320d.lib
opencv_imgproc320d.lib
opencv_ml320d.lib
opencv_objdetect320d.lib
opencv_photo320d.lib
opencv_shape320d.lib
opencv_stitching320d.lib
opencv_superres320d.lib
opencv_ts320d.lib
opencv_video320d.lib
opencv_videoio320d.lib
opencv_videostab320d.lib
```

I badly need this work :( . It should be noted that I have quadruple-checked the instructions to make this work, so I don't think it has to do with the header files or something.

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing versions of Visual Studio (pay careful attention the 2 digit VC version is not the same as the Visual Studio year for all versions other than 2010) or using a 32bit lib on a 64 bit build or viseversa.

Comment: In my above comment I assume you verified that `opencv_calib3d320d.lib` exists and you properly set the linker path for the debug configuration.

Comment: ***The odd part is that the namespace 'cv' works fine*** Headers and libraries are handled separately.